# R regex: match strings with two words near each other with exception

Tags: r, regex, grepl

**What I did**

I wrote a regex that matches all text strings with `"A"` and `"BV"` with 0-10 words between using this tutorial: https://www.regular-expressions.info/near.html

```
df<- data.frame(text=c("ART 6 dasd asd NOT art 2 BV","NOT ART 6 ds as dd BV","ART 6 NO BV"),
                id=c(1,2,3))



subset(df, grepl("(ART)(?:\\W+\\w+){0,10}?\\W+(\\bBV\\b)",
                   perl=TRUE,
                   ignore.case = TRUE,
                   text))


                         text id
1 ART 6 dasd asd NOT art 2 BV  1
2       NOT ART 6 ds as dd BV  2
3                 ART 6 NO BV  3
```

**What I am trying to get**

Now I would like to rewrite the regex that it does not match if there occurs any word of a list (i.e. `NOT` and `NO` in the example data) in the 0-10 words between "A" and "BV".

So the result would look like:

```
subset(df, grepl("NEWREGEX",
                   perl=TRUE,
                   ignore.case = TRUE,
                   text))


                         text id
1        NOT ART 6 ds as dd BV  2
```

I think I could use something like `?!` but I could not figure it out

Comment: Just to clarify.  Do you consider `ART 6 ds as dd BVAT'` as  a match

Comment: no, only ` BV ` should match

Comment: Then I would create a second `&!grepl("NOT?", text)` i.e. `subset(df, grepl("(ART)(?:\\W+\\w+){0,10}?\\W+(\\bBV\\b)",
+                    perl=TRUE,
+                    ignore.case = TRUE,
+                    text) & !grepl("NOT?", text, ignore.case = TRUE))`

Comment: I agree, but every word from the exclusion list could appear somewhere before  `"A" ` or after  `"B"`. I corrected the sample data

Comment: Then try `library(stringr);str_extract(df$text, "(A\\w+\\b.*\\bBV\\b)") %>% str_detect("NOT?") %>% '!' %>% magrittr::extract(df, ., )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **akrun** we have a really nice solution:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(df$text, "(A\\w+\\b.*\\bBV\\b)") %>% str_detect("NOT?") %>% '!' %>% magrittr::extract(df, ., )
```